# Nested types in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, class-hierarchy, nested-types

I have UICollectionView with cells: Image, Text, or Image+Text.

```
class ParentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    class ImageCell: ParentCell {
        class TextCell: ImageCell { }
    }
    class TextCell: ParentCell { }
}
func createTextCellId(classPrefix: ParentCell.Type) -> String {
    return String(reflecting: classPrefix.TextCell)
}
```

Why Swift erases nested type?

```
// CORRECT: ParentCell.TextCell
createTextCellId(classPrefix: ParentCell.self)

// INCORRECT: ParentCell.TextCell
createTextCellId(classPrefix: ParentCell.ImageCell.self)
```

Another functions do not work:

```
func createTextCellId<ParentCellType: ParentCell>(classPrefix: ParentCellType.Type) -> String {
    return String(reflecting: classPrefix.TextCell)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how Swift works. `classPrefix.TextCell` in your code will always mean the `TextCell` declared in `ParentCell`, not the one in `ImageCell`.

To do this kind of dynamically resolution of types, you would need a protocol:

```
protocol TextCellProviding: UICollectionViewCell {
    associatedtype TextCell: UICollectionViewCell
}
```

Then you can do:

```
func createTextCellId<Cell: TextCellProviding>(classPrefix: Cell.Type) -> String {
    return String(reflecting: classPrefix.TextCell)
}
```

Then your design could be:

```
class ParentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
}

class ImageCell: ParentCell, TextCellProviding {
    typealias TextCell = ImageAndTextCell
}

// You can nest ImageAndTextCell in ImageCell if you want, but I think it is less readable that way
// Perhaps LabelledImageCell could be a better name? Or ImageCell.Labelled
class ImageAndTextCell: ImageCell { }

class TextOnlyCell: ParentCell, TextCellProviding {
    typealias TextCell = TextOnlyCell
}
```

Note that `ParentCell` cannot conform to `TextCellProviding`. Otherwise the same problem happens again - i.e. `ParentCell` decides what `TextCell` should be, for all its subclasses, and its subclasses can't change that.

Example:

```
createTextCellId(classPrefix: TextOnlyCell.self) // TextOnlyCell
createTextCellId(classPrefix: ImageCell.self) // ImageAndTextCell
```

Also consider whether you actually need `ParentCell`. If all the common functionalities can be (and makes sense to be) implemented with extensions on `TextCellProviding`, consider doing that instead.